# Python3 exception in package VCFPy

Tags: python-3.x, vcf-vcard

I am trying to use the VCFPy package in Python3. Here are the first two lines of my program:

```
import vcfpy
reader = vcfpy.Reader("example_file.vcf")
```

and I get the error message:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/vcfpy/parser.py", line 701, in **init**
> self._line = stream.readline()  # trailing '\n'
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'

The program is running under Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `vcfpy.Reader.from_path('example_file.vcf')`.

The Reader constructor accepts a stream, not a filename.

Comment: Now it complains about my input format my VCF file:  

IncorrectVCFFormat('Missing line starting with "#CHROM"') 

I will try to figure out the problem.  The file is the contact list of my Android phone.